# boost::interprocess::scoped_lock not unlocking the mutex

Tags: c++, boost

I use a boost named_mutex to check if there is already a mutex with the corresponding name,  and if it is to halt the program because i want to stop other instances of my app to be ran.

I do this. **at the beginning** of the program:

```
try {
    boost::interprocess::named_mutex mutex_to_lock(boost::interprocess::open_only, "scilock");
    exit(0);
} catch (...) {
    boost::interprocess::named_mutex mutex_to_lock(boost::interprocess::create_only, "scilock");
    boost::interprocess::scoped_lock locking(mutex_to_lock);
}

*rest of the program...*
```

It tries to open a mutex first, if it exists, it exits, and if one doesn't exists it throws an exception meaning that we can go ahead and create one. I use a scoped_lock on the mutex so I don't have to manage the unlocking of it (**it should unlock even if the app crashes**), however it does not unlock it at all. the mutex remains closed after the program ends.

i have tried using named_recursive_mutex, even though I don't think it helps with anything

i have also tried this format:

```
    boost::interprocess::named_mutex mutex_to_lock(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, "scilock");
    boost::interprocess::scoped_lock locking(mutex_to_lock, boost::interprocess::try_lock);
    if (!lock) // if it didnt manage to lock (meaning that probably it is already locked)
        exit(0);
```

but overall same results.

If it helps with anything, I am using Fedora 36, with boost 1.76

Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>

int main() {
  boost::interprocess::named_mutex mutex_to_lock(
      boost::interprocess::open_or_create, "sci");
  boost::interprocess::scoped_lock locking(mutex_to_lock,
                                           boost::interprocess::try_to_lock);

  if (!locking) {
    printf("exiting..");
    exit(0);
  }

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

  return 0;
}
```

The mutex is not being unlocked on app termination, which is not what i want. I want it closed even if the program is being terminated

Comment: The scope of `scoped_lock locking` ends with the `catch`. How do you know, that the mutex is not unlocked?

Comment: _"if one doesnt exists it throws an exception meaning that we can go ahead and create one"_ - You can try, but another process could already have created the mutex between the throw and the catch.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I know that the mutex is not unlocked because it does not let me open another instance of my application.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that is not very likely to happen, though it is something to think about

Comment: @stephan Those unlikely things happen all the time. :) Anyway, the `named_mutex` will continue to exist even after your program has terminated unless you use `named_mutex::remove()` to remove it

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, i dont really care about that. I care about the **scoped_lock** unlocking my mutex only, that is what i need. The mutex will anyway remove itself when the program ends

Comment: @stephan Then please show a [mre]. I do not get the behavior you describe. For me, it's unlocked directly when the `scoped_lock` goes out of scope.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I Have made a mre. Check my edit on the post. It does not unlock the mutex on termination (i want to have it closed)

Comment: Must be a bug in your implementation. Your program unlocks the mutex fine for me (Fedora 35, boost is the latest from github

Comment: @TedLyngmo My bug is that **i dont close it peacefully using return 0;**. I close from another function using exit(0), so it doesnt allow the scoped lock to unlock the mutex, but it should do that. I was previously using file_lock, but for some reason it does not work on windows, only on linux.

Comment: Then make your mutex and lock global. The exit will destruct global objects.

Comment: @stephan _"I close from another function using exit(0)"_ -  Ok, then read [`std::exit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit): _"Stack is not unwound: destructors of variables with automatic storage duration are not called."_ - If you had made a [mre] that actually did what you describe in the comments, this could have been cleared up much faster.

Comment: @stephan Yes it will work, unless you have other hidden things in your actual code that we can't see.

Comment: @TedLyngmo when i was using file_lock, it could succesfully unlock the file upon calling exit(0);.

Comment: @stephan Presumably, that `file_lock` wasn't a variable with automatic storage duration - or it doesn't require a destructor to unlock.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Nevermind. i got it working. Thank you so much. Ted, I am very sorry for all the hassle. Have a good day!